# Whatsapp message: extract date

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp

Working in Python + Selenium, how may I extract date data from a WhatsApp message ?

Background: I get a bunch of images daily. I need to process only today's lot.

What I have done till now: I have reached the grid in the "media, links and docs" sub-section.
The outer HTML of a (random) image is:

```
<div role="listitem" aria-label=" image" tabindex="-1" class="g0rxnol2 d0st09ow ikc09dv3 hha4v2jc gfz4du6o r7fjleex bazijzwv n0hkwe29 fvb4mgxr ho9ovbg7 tcg15ap9 c5wy1lv0 bqysl6j9"><div class="lhggkp7q qq0sjtgm tkdu00h0 b9fczbqn cm280p3y ln8gz9je ppled2lx gfz4du6o r7fjleex m62443ks rqga0wu5 ayqm650w sb46ev41 q8kvkxy1 d1poss59 gyj32ejw cmcp1to6 eg0col54 fl2x09zf r2wk4q3o nnij903c lr2nq6lc pcik6s50 oxe6ytxh"><div class="p357zi0d lhggkp7q mf2g8abl lrw9n60e"></div></div><div class="t3g6t33p qnwaluaf cm280p3y ajgl1lbb ppled2lx tukmaf4q lhggkp7q qq0sjtgm p5jrpzbl g6mp970w ln8gz9je jnl3jror"><div class="g0rxnol2 ln8gz9je ppled2lx"><div class="lhggkp7q jnl3jror p357zi0d gndfcl4n ac2vgrno ln8gz9je ppled2lx"><button class="i5tg98hk f9ovudaz przvwfww gx1rr48f shdiholb phqmzxqs gtscxtjd ajgl1lbb thr4l2wc fl2x09zf r2wk4q3o nnij903c lr2nq6lc" tabindex="-1" type="button"><div class="t3g6t33p qnwaluaf cm280p3y ajgl1lbb ppled2lx tukmaf4q lhggkp7q qq0sjtgm p5jrpzbl g6mp970w ln8gz9je jnl3jror"></div></button></div><div class="lhggkp7q jnl3jror p357zi0d gndfcl4n ac2vgrno ln8gz9je ppled2lx"><button class="i5tg98hk f9ovudaz przvwfww gx1rr48f shdiholb phqmzxqs gtscxtjd ajgl1lbb thr4l2wc fl2x09zf r2wk4q3o nnij903c lr2nq6lc" tabindex="-1" type="button"><div class="t3g6t33p qnwaluaf cm280p3y ajgl1lbb ppled2lx tukmaf4q lhggkp7q qq0sjtgm p5jrpzbl g6mp970w ln8gz9je jnl3jror"><div class="t3g6t33p qnwaluaf cm280p3y ajgl1lbb ppled2lx tukmaf4q lhggkp7q qq0sjtgm p5jrpzbl g6mp970w ln8gz9je jnl3jror" style="background-image: url(&quot;blob:https://web.whatsapp.com/bd45c444-3e4d-41e6-a8f7-107e40f7ff57&quot;);"></div></div></button></div></div></div><div style="padding-top: 100%;"></div></div>
```

and the xpath is

```
//*@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div[5]/span/div/span/div/div[2]/span/div/div/div[1]/div/div[22]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button/div/div
```

I regex the image as:

```
blob:https://web.whatsapp.com/bd45c444-3e4d-41e6-a8f7-107e40f7ff57
```

All is working fine, can someone guide me on how to access the date?

Comment: where is the date value in the reference HTML?

Comment: @KunduK: that essentially is my problem. I cannot identify the div containing date data. Also, even if I use the search bar to identify today's message, I cannot use the data to loop over all today's messages. Please help.